# Listing the average from the top 5 scores of each player

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, correlated-subquery

After reading several other answers of similar problems, I still can't wrap my head to achieve the following:

Having a list of player scores, I would like to get the top *n* scores of each player (the scores table only has the player id and a value).  The final purpose is to aggregate the scores with the `AVG()` function.

Also note that the *n* bound is just a limit; a player may have less than *n* scores, in which case all of them should be computed.

Once the results are calculated, joining with the player table will allow to expand each player id into printable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from here:

```
drop table if exists scores;
create table scores (playerid integer, score integer);
insert into scores values 
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4);

select p1.playerid, p1.score
from scores p1, scores p2
where p1.playerid = p2.playerid
and 
p1.score >=
ifnull((select score 
 from scores 
 where playerid=p1.playerid 
 order by score desc limit 4,1
),0)
group by p1.playerid,p1.score;
```

which will give you the desired list of top scores.

Comment: Very clever.  I actually managed to simplify it by not joining the scores table with itself and still get the average I was looking for.  Nonetheless, the subquery inside `ifnull` is an impressively smart solution.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my opinion, this query has two major problems: has a correlated subquery (for each row of player you execte a subquery) and, the result for a player can contains more than 5 values if scores in top scores for this player has duplicate values.

Comment: @danihp: Certainly, the query is less correct but much simpler than the version using vars.  In my case I can handle that tradeoff because scores are floats entered with two decimal places so is quite difficult to have duplicates there.  Besides, for averaging purposes is no big deal considering the low probability of duplicates.

Comment: @C2H5OH, simple is good, I also think that is better in some cases (one execution only) readability than performance. How many rows are you handling? More that 10000 players? If is the case, only with academical aim, can you test both queries and post result times? regards.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you need vars to accomplish yours requirements:

```
select
    idplayer, Score
from
(
    select
        idplayer, T.Score,
        @r := IF(@g=idplayer,@r+1,1) RowNum,
        @g := idplayer
    from (select @g:=null) initvars
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT s.Score, 
               s.idplayer
        FROM scores s
        ORDER BY idplayer, s.score DESC
    ) T
) U
WHERE RowNum <= 3
```

[Test it at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06278/5/0):

```
create table scores( idplayer int, score int);
insert into scores values 
   (1,5),     (1,7),      (1,18),      (1,27),      (2,6);
```

Results:

```
| IDPLAYER | SCORE |
--------------------
|        1 |    27 |
|        1 |    18 |
|        1 |     7 |
|        2 |     6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work in mysql.  However, the following captures the idea as a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(score)
        from (select score
              from scores s
              where s.playerid = p.playerid
              order by score desc
              limit 5
             ) s2
       ) as summax5
from players p
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work.  The problem is that the second subquery is correlated (the subquery after the `from` clause), so it cannot access columns from the outer queries.

Comment: Correlated subquery do access values from outer levels.  I'm pretty sure they can reach out as far as they need. (The equivalent query works in SQL Server for instance, using TOP instead of LIMIT.)  If you have the syntax right, this may be a limitation of mysql.  You might be able to chain the equalities, by introducing "where s2.playerid = p.playerid" in the middle query, and then "s.playerid = s2.playerid" in the inner one.

Comment: Yes, but MySQL in particular, [restricts correlated subqueries in the `FROM` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html).